# APIs are not responding fast is APP is using Multipeer Connectivity framework

Tags: ios, api, afnetworking, multipeer-connectivity

I am using Multipeer Connectivity Framework in my APP and its working absolutely fine but when APP is invoking any API or downloading any file from server then its delaying the response. Sometimes its failed and sometimes I am getting Time out error.

I have also checked "Network" status on xCode debug navigator and found that speed is going up and down instantly and never going beyond 6kb/s and sometimes its showing as 0 kb/s but when I disable Multipeer Connectivity then it works fine and speed going at 70kb/s too.

I have also noticed that if bluetooth is ON then its happening not with the Wifi.

Any suggestion would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when advertising, **Multipeer always advertises on the wifi** (there's no way to say bluetooth only). The way it advertises is by **switching the wifi access mode into adhoc multiple times per second** to find other peers, then switching back to AP mode (ie. resuming its connection to your wifi router). Doing this is **highly disruptive to large transfers**.

You have two options to fix this:

1) as soon as you can, after getting connected, call `stopAdvertising()`. This will stop the wifi mode from being constantly changed, and your throughput will resume at its normal rate. Warning: you cannot micro-manage this, because it takes up to 30 seconds after calling `stopAdvertising()` until it takes effect

2) switch from Multipeer to an alternative framework that allows you to specify bluetooth-only, and only use bluetooth. I wrote one called [BluePeer](https://github.com/xaphod/Bluepeer) which I use in my apps. It is unicast (not multicast) and supports roles like Client/Server (as well as role-less like Multipeer)